# PLay! framework. How to separate layout to blocks looks like php blocks?

Tags: playframework

In php we can separate our site to several blocks(header,navigation,content,footer)
Looks like  `<?include ?>`
 in php,can I use some method for including partial to layout in play???

Comment: What have you done to try and accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into [basic documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaTemplateUseCases) search for ***tags*** and ***includes***